# Java HashMap iteration Map.Entry<> vs Entry<>

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iteration

I am new to Java and writing java on a Mac using HashMap. 
However I encountered a problem that I can't find the answer

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("a", 1);
        hm.put("b", 2);
        for (Entry<String, Integer> en : hm.entrySet()) {  //this line is different
            System.out.print(en.getKey());
            System.out.println(en.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine on a windows machine, but on my Mac it pops out an error indicating that "can not find symbol: Entry "

Later I changed code to

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("a", 1);
        hm.put("b", 2);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : hm.entrySet()) {  //this line is different
            System.out.print(en.getKey());
            System.out.println(en.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

And now it works fine.

Can anybody tell me why? 
Why this code works fine on others computer but not on mine?

Comment: Because you didn't import `Entry`.

Comment: In the second set of code, you are essentially telling the compiler that the iterations are for 'java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer>' the first entry does not specify. Are you doing this in an IDE? The first would probably work if you also imported 'java.util.Map.Entry'

Comment: @immibis Entry is an inner class of interface Map, so not needed to import it.

Comment: @hiren You can either import `Entry`, or you can import `Map` and write `Map.Entry`, or you can import neither and write `java.util.Map.Entry`

Comment: @hiren Entry is an inner interface, those are automatically static - so you'll have to import them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you provided does not compile on windows as well.
Not sure you may be compiling something else.
Things can happen if you are using console and trying to compile and you have similar file names. 
 
Map.Entry resides in **java.util.Map** package.
So, my suggestion would be 
 
1. You can import **java.util.Map.Entry** in your code. 
OR 
2. Use **Map.Entry** instead of just Entry, something like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : hm.entrySet())
```

Basically when you use Map.Entry you are directly referencing to that class.
Java's import statement is pure syntactical sugar. import is only evaluated at compile time to indicate to the compiler where to find the names in the code.

You may live without any import statement when you always specify the full qualified name of classes. Like this line needs no import statement at all:

```
javax.swing.JButton but = new  javax.swing.JButton();
```

The import statement will make your code more readable like this:

```
import javax.swing.*
JButton but = new JButton();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks JustAditya, I was using an IDE on Win. now I know where I got wrong~

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this compiles in windows?

I just put this in a file called "C:\tmp\etc\Test.java" then did this...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Bret>cd \tmp\etc

C:\tmp\etc>javac Test.java
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    for (Entry<String, Integer> en : hm.entrySet()) {  //this line is different
         ^
  symbol:   class Entry
  location: class Test
1 error

C:\tmp\etc>
```

You must be doing something else that causes this...